# Delta handling in GoogleClassroom

Tags: google-classroom

We are integrating Google Classroom to sync data to our Application from GoogleClassroom.

We have the following queries :-

1. Let's say today we fetched data from Google Classroom and we got a Course named as XYZ".
2. After 1 week again we fetched the data and above retrieved course i.e. "XYZ" got deleted / inactive then it will come with type as "Deleted/ Inactive.

How long does this delete /inactive event for this courses will come. and how we can handle deltas after doing first sync.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to understand what you're asking partially do to language.  Let me see if I can understand.

Are you asking how long a course will be marked as "archived" after it was changed to archived by the user?  If so, the answer should be "indefinitely."

If you're asking a different question, perhaps showing us what code you're using or API endpoints you're hitting, along with its return information, will help us understand.